# OpenGL и WinForms(Panel)

Tags: visual-c++, winforms, opengl

Кто нибудь сталкивался с инициализацией **OpenGL** в **WinForms** не на *Форму* целиком, а к примеру на *Панель* или какой другой компонент.
Был бы очень доволен, если бы кто-нибудь выложил код (желательно с++).

П.С. Фреймворки и сторонние компоненты не предалагать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обязательно на компонент? Можно просто кинуть на форму, но создать viewport не на полный размер формы.

Comment: Если есть пример кода прошу поделиться, хотелось бы как-то разграничить, но такой вариант тоже интересен, что-то я не подумал.

Answer (score 0):

Ой, а что мешает получить DС(графический контекст контрола) по его hWnd(хэндлу)(если ничего не путаю, достаточно вызвать GetDC(hWnd)) и инициализировать контекст OpenGL как обычно? Я в своё время так и делал. Получается именно то, чего ожидают =) Правда, есть и минусы: для каждого контрола контекст будет свой, и при желании отобразить один и тот же меш, допустим, с нескольких ракурсов, придётся загружать массив треугольников, текстуры и шейдеры в каждый контекст отдельно.